# detect orientation of sub image

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, orientation

i have a scanned form. but, some times, the scanned forms are skewed. so, i want to automatically detect the orientation of the scanned pdf, rotate it so that it text in it will be exactly horizontal with minimal error.

My idea is described as below:
The Form has few printed logos. so, what i thought is that, since i already have exact logo which is horizontal,somehow i compare it with the scanned image and see how much angle it is in the scanned image. if i can get the angle, i will rotate the pdf by this angle. i searched a lot, but what i got is template matching, which is telling me whether this particular logo is in the image or not. can some one help me how to detect angle by using my concept in python using opencv or some other package

---

@EDIT

[image: Actual Form]

[image: Logo]

In the above pictures, i want to detect the angle of the Logo in the actual images.

Comment: why not using letter orientation and border's contrast ?

Comment: @Dadep, what do you mean by letter orientation, how can i do that?

Comment: Have a look : https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/ff03/c89c70529a951bf966a31405b794a5411d8a.pdf

Comment: @Dadep could you please provide some insights on application of border's contrast for document orientation calculation?

Comment: @flamelite using edge dectection. based on something that look like : https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/09/01/build-kick-ass-mobile-document-scanner-just-5-minutes/ then find angle and rotate

Comment: thanks @Dadep i looked that source but i think that might not work in scanned documents since here we don't have document edges separating the background.

Comment: you can associate shape detection, often appear a thin shadow between the sheet and tha background

Comment: I am just wondering, if i just want to know the angle of the logo in the scanned image, how can i do it.

Comment: Can you please upload an image from your scanner? You can blur out any sensitive information - we just need to get an idea for the logo's appearance/size.

Comment: But this image is good, so where is your skewed image? And where is the logo?

Comment: This is the original non skewed Image, the logo is the MEDWATCH image below the main image. some times while scanning, the image will be skewed, so..i want to use logo to determine how skewed the image is.@Silencer